# Timeout for AngularJs promises and Play! actions

Tags: angularjs, scala, playframework, angular-promise, concurrent.futures

Hy guys,

I am building an app that has Angular on the front end and Scala Play! in the backend.
I was wondering, how can I specify timeout values for both $q promises and Scala Futures returned from the Async Actions?

I think the timeout would be useful both on the server and on the client(will provide useful insight to improve the performance and better user experience).

Do you think **timeouts are necessary?** and if yes can you give me **some pointers on the implementation** on both client and server side.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://bahmutov.calepin.co/angular-q-promises-with-timeouts.html

Answer (score 0):

For the frontend - no `$timeout`'s are not necessary because of the built in promises to resolve async calls to your backend via your services.

There are lots of questions on SO that detail how to use them but here's a basic structure:

```
function getData() {
  return $http.get('path-to-api/api.json').then( 
    function success(result) {
      // Do stuff with it
      return result.data;
    },
    function failure(err) {
      return err;
    });
}
```

See the angular docs [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) for more info.

Comment: I think by `timeout` Adrian means a way to reject a promise after a certain amount of time if it's neither resolved nor rejected normally.

Comment: @AlecKravets Ah - i see - you're right - I skimmed the question

Comment: @AlecKravets yes, thank you, this is exactly what I meant

Comment: @Katana24 thank you for your effort in answering, I've upvoted you but this is not displayed yet, thanks to my non-existent yet reputation(SO policy)

Comment: @Adrian Great - glad you found the answer